# to get instance/name/url of child jsp in parent jsp?

Tags: jsp

Can anyone help me on below query:

Suppose i have 1 parent JSP and 10 child JSP.

All 10 child JSP extending parent JSP for header part of UI.

If I specify title tag in child JSP then it will go in body tag of all JSPs. 
But it should present in head tag to remove accessibility related error( WAVE 1.1.6 accessibility tool gives following error - **"Title is missing or not informative"**).

If I specify title tag in parent JSP, we are successfully able to remove this accessibility error.

And now title tag will come under head part of html.
But to add title tag in parent JSP, we need to identify the reference/instance of each child JSP in parent JSP and then put condition in parent JSP for respective child JSP and add title tag for each child JSP under if condition.

I have tried below scriplet in  parent JSP to get instance of child JSP :

```
String getURL=request.getRequestURI();
out.print(getURL);
```

Above scriplet is giving url of parent JSP only.
So, is there any way to get instance/name/url of child JSP in parent JSP?

Comment: try this `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")`

Comment: try this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796931/setting-parent-jsp-variables-in-child-jsp

Comment: There is no such thing as a "child" jsp.