# Passing a variable from child JSP to parent JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I have two JSP pages `a.jsp` and `b.jsp`. And **a.jsp** includes **b.jsp**

**a.jsp**

```
<jsp:include page="b.jsp" >
  <jsp:param name="pageName" value="create" />
</jsp:include>
```

I am able to pass the value of variable `pageName` to **b.jsp** where I retrieve it by

**b.jsp**

```
<h1>This is a ${param.pageName} page<br>
<input type="text" name="userInput">
```

Now I want to send the value in the input element `userInput` back to **a.jsp** ( I want to use **b.jsp** as a child page with three parent jsp pages and the entered value will be different for all three parent pages **a.jsp**, **b.jsp** and **c.jsp**)

```
<h1>The user input entered in the child jsp is :<>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Store it in the session. Store it in a cookie. Note that the user will not provide input until long after (in computing terms) the page is sent.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can i just do  something like `In parent request.setAttribute("myAttrName", initialvalue); In child JSP - request.setAttribute("myAttrName", newvalue); Then in parent JSP after the jsp:include of the child, get the value - String result = (String)request.getAttribute("myAttrName");` instead of putting in session or cookie? This is one of the suggested approaches here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796931/setting-parent-jsp-variables-in-child-jsp?rq=1

Comment: I don't see why not. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: This question is confusing. I guess you ultimately want to ask "How to show the user input entered?", then the answer is: "Add a submit button to the form and then you can show it with `${param.userInput}` after pressing the submit button". Nothing of this all is related to include files. You'd have had exactly the same problem when having everything in a single JSP page (which is in the end probably also much easier for you in order to unit-test and to formulate an understandable question).